# How to get physical size of Screen?

Tags: android, blackberry

For BlackBerry and Android.

How to get physical width and height of Screen (not resolution) in inches or centimeters?

Is there any method to do it?

Many thanks !

Comment: See this post, may be its helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions

Comment: This is two distinct questions.  Please separate out Android and Blackberry into separate questions on stackoverflow. They don't have much in common.

Answer (score 1):

Use for Blackberry ::

```
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;

int DeviceHeight = Display.getHeight();
int DeviceWidth = Display.getWidth();
```

for Android ::

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 

int DeviceHeight = display.getHeight();
int DeviceWidth = display.getWidth();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to get physical width and height of Screen (not resolution size).